# Horizontally scrollable gallery of videos that play on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a gallery of images that, when hovered upon, the image disappears and a video begins playing, similar to Netflix. I was able to create a gallery that did what I want here:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.container img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/check-back-soon-hand-lettering-600w-1379832464.jpg>
```

and the image disappearing and video playing on hover that I want here:

```js
const videos = document.querySelectorAll(".polystar");

for (const video of videos) {
  video.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    video.play()
  }, false);
  video.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    video.pause()
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.gallery-cv {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
}

.polystar {
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

.top-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 535px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.polystar:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1> headline </h1>
<div class="gallery-cv">

  <img class="top-img first" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">

  <video class='polystar' muted src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/432406907.hd.mp4?s=f35b5f202d573efa75d9293d213fc3be0927fd85&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
          
            <img class="top-img second" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
          
              <img class="top-img third" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
          </div>
```

But when I try to combine these (as I've attempted in the above codepen), my gallery disappears and I'm left with only one image, despite having others present in the html. I'm guessing this has something to do with me losing my gallery when I try to have the images inside it absolutely positioned, but I'm not sure how else to achieve my hover effect without absolutely positioning them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems we have to solve. Lets start with the image that should be displayed by default and disappear for the video on hover:

1. We need a wrapping element that contains the video and the image like a `<div>`.
2. We apply `position: relative;` to the parent element (wrapper)
3. We apply `position: absolute; inset: 0;` (inset: 0 = top + right + bottom + left: 0;) to have the image span the entire wrapping element and elevate it layer-wise above the video with a positive z-index: `z-index: 1;`
4. to hide the image on hover we use: `div:hover img { display: none; }`

The next issue is to start playing the video on hover. For that we need JS which we also can do with the `onmouseover`-attribute: `onmouseover="element.play();"`

To pause the video when you not hovering we can use JS or the `onmouseout`-attribute: `onmouseout="element.pause();"`

Both the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` trigger/attribute must be added to the wrapping parent element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:hover img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="document.querySelector('video').play();" onmouseout="document.querySelector('video').pause();">
  <video>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank tacoshy for the help. After some slight tweaks to what you suggested I was able to achieve my scrollable video gallery dreams. I made each image it's own div, with display: inline-block and then wrapped them all in a container div, which had display: flex and overflow-x:auto to have the scrollable effect. Then instead of having the div disappear on hover, I gave each image its' own class and made that disappear on hover, so that only the image that was being hovered over would have that affect.

Here's a link to that code:

https://codepen.io/jack-mullinkosson/pen/JjJWWN